# Error with loading/installing the schedule python module

Tags: python, schedule

i'm having issues with a test script for scheduling.

I need to do 2 groups of actions, the first group at one moment of each day, the second group in another moment of each day.

this is my code

```
import time
import schedule


def testA():
    print("test A")

def TestB():

    print("test B")

schedule.every().day.at("12:12").do(testA)
schedule.every().day.at("12:14").do(testB)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

not sure if the code is correct and will do what i need to, but at the moment it doesn't run at all, i get the following error

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schedule'**

I installed it with pip, in fact if i try to do **pip install schedule**
i get **Requirement already satisfied: schedule in c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (1.1.0)**

how can i fix this? thank you

Comment: Have you tried "python3 -m pip install schedule" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve the problem

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (1.1.0)")
    
import time
import schedule


def testA():
    print("test A")

def TestB():

    print("test B")

schedule.every().day.at("12:12").do(testA)
schedule.every().day.at("12:14").do(testB)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: sadly same error :( what else can be?

Comment: ok i removed the version (1.1.0) from the string and it worked! 
now i can run the script once and it will run everyday at the given time?

Comment: thanks. If Windows is not running at all when your computer is off so the Scheduler isn’t running either. if on, then yes it should work. by the way, i would suggest creating virtual environment for each project to avoid those path problems.